Paragraph indents dissapeared suddenly
At some point my paragraph indents dissapeared... I cannot recall when. Why is this happening? Here is a MWE that does not work for me
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % Justify

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

This is the first paragraph of the test section. It serves as an introduction to the content that follows. Here, we briefly discuss the general topic and set the stage for more detailed information. This paragraph should be indented according to the document’s formatting settings.


The second paragraph continues from the previous one, providing additional context or details. As with the first paragraph, it should adhere to the document’s indentation rules. The purpose here is to ensure that the indentation behaves consistently throughout the document, giving a uniform appearance to each new paragraph.


Finally, the third paragraph wraps up the section. It summarizes the key points discussed and may provide a transition to the next section or topic. This concluding paragraph also follows the same indentation pattern as the previous ones, ensuring a cohesive and organized layout.


\end{document}



You've given us a lot of code to go through.  Please trim down your preamble to the minimal amount of code that reproduces your issue.

sorry, its reduced. Ive narrowed it down to \usepackage[document]{ragged2e} % Justify

In fact, if I include the package I need to include \justify in the document to return to normal behaviour...

@lukygee ... then don't include it, or at least not with the document option

There are essentially no reasons to use \justify.  As here, if you find yourself using it, it is almost always just covering up for an earlier error. Note your original preamble had other errors, incompatible packages (you can not load enumerate and enumitem) packages that do nothing (inputenc, epstopdf ) and almost certainly multiple packages you do not use in the document.

Is there a way to tell which packages are actually not being used in the document? I could remove them and not notice an issue which is generally why some are there. For example, i remember having issues with Ø, and some German letters and finding the solution to be this inputenc. I do not want to remove it then find later that my document which has been shared is missing these characters

Your (now no longer shown) preamble is a real mess. Mixing package loading and settings makes it very difficult to maintain.
Anyway, the problem is obviously
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

From the manual

When under \RaggedRight, the paragraph indentation is set to zero.


Your (now no longer shown) preamble is a real mess.
Assuming I am using these packages, what exactly makes it a mess? Just having a lot of them? I hear this a lot but fail to see how this is anything other than a latex issue


@lukygee It's unmaintainable: you can't know where a package is actually loaded and you risk incompatibilities. For example you have both enumerate and enumitem (a big no-no), hyperref is in the wrong place (it should be loaded last with a few exceptions); epstopdf is completely useless. By the way =0 in the definition of \track should not be immediately followed by %; what you do in \getCurrentSectionNumber is correct.

okay so I could remove 2 packages and a % symbol, it will hardly clean up the preamble (btw I agree it's a mess, but there's not really much that can be done it seems). Where is one supposed to learn that, for example, enumerate and enumitem together is "a big no no", and that epstopdf is useless? Most of these things come from this very website when I ask e.g. "how to display eps in latex?" and get told to use epstopdf
